# Java JDBC, работа с PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc

Здравствуйте, необходимо сделать одно DAO, и в нём 2 PreparedStatement (для каждого из методов), один я создаю и использую, а второй не выходит, при условии что закрытие должно происходить 1 раз, и методы должны чередоваться в цикле 5 раз, т.е. необходимо сделать следующее:
создать по полю для каждого метода, при вызове метода поле инициализировать, при последующих вызовах - использовать уже инициализированное значение, все поля закрыть в одном методе, в конце работы. как это реализовать? помогите пожалуйста

```
public class ProfileDAOImpl implements ProfileDAO {
    private Connection connection = null;
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

public void getConn() throws DAOException {
    try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("db.properties")) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(reader);
        String user = properties.getProperty("user");
        String password = properties.getProperty("password");
        String dburl = properties.getProperty("dburl");
        String driver = properties.getProperty("driver");
        Class.forName(driver);
        if (connection == null) {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, user, password);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new DAOException("file error ",e);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new DAOException("class error ",e);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new DAOException("conn error ",e);
    }
}
private PreparedStatement getPreparedStatement(String sql) throws DAOException{
    if(preparedStatement == null) {
        try {
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DAOException("create ps error ",e);
        }
    } return preparedStatement;
}
@Override
public void updateProfile(Profile profile) throws DAOException {
    String sql = "UPDATE Profile SET user_name=?," +
            " nick_name=?, user_mail=?, password=? WHERE id=?";
    try {
        getPreparedStatement(sql);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, profile.getUserName());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, profile.getNickName());
        preparedStatement.setString(3, profile.getUserMail());
        preparedStatement.setString(4, profile.getPassword());
        preparedStatement.setInt(5, profile.getId());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DAOException("update error ",e);
    }
}
@Override
public void close() throws DAOException{
    try {
        if (preparedStatement != null) {
            preparedStatement.close();
            preparedStatement = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DAOException("Close (ps) error ",e);
    }
    try {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
            connection = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DAOException("Close (conn) error",e);
    }
}
@Override
public void createProfile (Profile profile) throws DAOException {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO Profile (user_name, nick_name, user_mail, password) " +
            "VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
    try {
        getPreparedStatement(sql);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, profile.getUserName());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, profile.getNickName());
        preparedStatement.setString(3, profile.getUserMail());
        preparedStatement.setString(4, profile.getPassword());
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DAOException("create error ",e);
    }
}
```

}

собственно необходимо чуть переписать метод main

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ProfileDAO profile = new ProfileDAOImpl(); 
    Profile Test = new Profile();
    Test.setUserName("Proverka");
    Test.setNickName("test");
    Test.setUserMail("@gmail.com");
    Test.setPassword("qwerty");
    Test.setId(2);

    try {
        profile.getConn();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            profile.updateProfile(Test);
            profile.createProfile(Test);
        }
        profile.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Накидал примерный вариант:

```
public class ProfileDAOImpl {
    private Connection connection = null;
    private Map<String, PreparedStatement> preparedStatements = new HashMap<String, PreparedStatement>();

    public void getConn() throws Exception {
        try(FileReader reader = new FileReader("db.properties")) {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(reader);
            String user = properties.getProperty("user");
            String password = properties.getProperty("password");
            String dburl = properties.getProperty("dburl");
            String driver = properties.getProperty("driver");
            Class.forName(driver);
            if(connection == null) {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, user, password);
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            throw new Exception("file error ", e);
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new Exception("class error ", e);
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            throw new Exception("conn error ", e);
        }
    }

    private PreparedStatement getPreparedStatement(String sql) throws Exception {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = preparedStatements.get(sql);
        if(preparedStatement == null) {
            try {
                preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                preparedStatements.put(sql, preparedStatement);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                throw new Exception("create ps error ", e);
            }
        }
        return preparedStatement;
    }

    public void updateProfile(Profile profile) throws Exception {
        String sql = "UPDATE Profile SET user_name=?," +
            " nick_name=?, user_mail=?, password=? WHERE id=?";
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getPreparedStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, profile.getUserName());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, profile.getNickName());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, profile.getUserMail());
            preparedStatement.setString(4, profile.getPassword());
            preparedStatement.setInt(5, profile.getId());
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("update error ", e);
        }
    }

    public void close() throws Exception {
        for(PreparedStatement preparedStatement : preparedStatements.values()) {
            try {
                if(preparedStatement != null) {
                    preparedStatement.close();
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                throw new Exception("Close (ps) error ", e);
            }
        }
        preparedStatements = null;
        try {
            if(connection != null) {
                connection.close();
                connection = null;
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Close (conn) error", e);
        }
    }

    public void createProfile(Profile profile) throws Exception {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO Profile (user_name, nick_name, user_mail, password) " +
            "VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getPreparedStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, profile.getUserName());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, profile.getNickName());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, profile.getUserMail());
            preparedStatement.setString(4, profile.getPassword());
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("create error ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

В коде заменил `DAOException` на `Exception`, чтобы было удобнее в Eclipse'е писать.

В новом варианте PreparedStatement сохраняются в карту, в которой ключ - это и есть сам запрос. В результате для разных запросов getPreparedStatement возвращает разные PreparedStatement, а не один и тот же как раньше. Вместо всего запроса в ключе можно использовать его хеш-сумму.

Также рекомендую сразу применять интерфейс [Closeable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html), чтобы не забыть закрыть DAO после использования.

Comment: благодарю, а можно допустим как то без map реализовать то что я описал выше?  (если с map, то методы update и прочее требует иного указания PreparedStatement, в поле он инициализирован с map)

Comment: Можно в методе `getPreparedStatement` не возвращать preparedStatement, а присваивать полю preparedStatement (добавить такое поле в класс). Но это как-то костыльно.